# How to export excel in ssrs 2005

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I'm having a problem "Data Regions within table/matrix cells are ignored" when exporting Microsoft Excel data in SSRS 2005.

How do I export Microsoft Excel data in SSRS 2005 when having Data Regions with table/matrix cells are ignored

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of the Excel renderer in SSRS 2005 - it won't render tables/matrices within tables/matrices. Your only option is to reformat your report to not have nested objects.